# Git のマージで「共通の祖先」は何故必要ですか？

Tags: git

[この記事](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v1/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%81%A8%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC)で下記の記述がありましたが

> 各ブランチが指すふたつのスナップショットとそれらの共通の先祖との間で三方向のマージを行いました。

ここでよくわからないのは、なぜマージするために、「共通の祖先」が必要なのかです。
２つのブランチの最後のコミットをマージすれば済む話だと思っていましたが、「共通の祖先」はどこで必要ですか？？不思議です。

Answer (score 31):

例えば、 hoge.txt というファイルを2つのブランチでそれぞれ変更した結果、次のようになっているとします。

branchA での hoge.txt

```
A
hoge
B
C
```

branchB での hoge.txt

```
A
B
piyo
C
```

この二つをマージしてみてください。できますか？

次のようなマージ結果が考えられますが、どれを選べばいいのでしょうか。

- 「元々なかった `hoge` と `piyo` をそれぞれ追加した」 両方含むのが正しい
- 「`hoge` と `piyo` をそれぞれ削除した」 どちらも含まないのが正しい
- 「実は branchA は何も変更していない」 branchB が正しい
- 「実は branchB は何も変更していない」 branchA が正しい
- 「そもそも `B` すらなかった」 両方で追加された `B` はどうすれば？
- etc...

これを判断するには、「**共通の祖先**に対して、それぞれがどう変更したのか」という情報が必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
最終的２つのブランチが同じCになったので、どちらかのCを取ればいいのでは？

Comment: 例示したのはコミットの流れではなく、あるファイルがそれぞれのブランチでどのような状態になっているかです。それぞれ4行のテキストファイルとして見てください。

Comment: 百聞は一見にしかず、というわけで、[実験用のリポジトリを作ってみました](https://github.com/yoh2/soj-10968)。 clone した後、branchA をチェックアウトして branchB をマージ、またはその逆を行ってみて下さい。branchA内、branchB内では、hoge1.txt ～ hoge5.txt はすべて同じ内容なのにもかかわらず、マージ結果が異なります。

Comment: 先程コメントした状態からアップデートしました。「２つのブランチの最後のコミットをマージすれば」とあったので、最後のコミットの、ひとつ前からの差分も共通となるよう調整。(禁断の push --force してるのでアップデート前に clone した方はご注意を)